# Confusion with forms for accepts_nested_attributes_for resources and unpermitted parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `accepts_nested_attributes_for` form in my rails app and I just can't get it to work. I keep getting `Unpermitted parameter` when trying to edit the parent object, even though I think I've permitted that param.

```
class Response < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :response_threads, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :response_threads
end

class ResponseThread < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :response
  has_many :response_thread_updates, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :response_thread_updates
end

class ResponseThreadUpdate < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :response_thread
end
```

In `responses_controller`:

```
def response_params
  params.require(:response).permit(:name, :response_thread, response_thread_attributes: [:id, :name] )
end
```

The form at `/responses/1/edit`:

```
<%= form_with(model: response) do |f| %>

  <%= f.fields_for :response_thread do |ff| %>
  
    <%= ff.label :name %>
    <%= ff.text_field :name %>
    
  <% end %>
  
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Here is my schema (updated and created datetimes removed):

```
create_table "responses", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name"
end

create_table "response_threads", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "response_id"
  t.string "name"
end

create_table "response_thread_updates", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "response_thread_id"
  t.string "name"
end
```

And the error:

```
Started PATCH "/responses/1" for ::1 at 2021-06-28 20:56:24 -0400
Processing by ResponsesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "response"=>{"response_thread"=>{"name"=>"asd"}}, "commit"=>"Update Response", "id"=>"1"}
  Response Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "responses".* FROM "responses" WHERE "responses"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/responses_controller.rb:63:in `set_response'
Unpermitted parameter: :response_thread
```

And my `routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :responses do
    resources :response_threads do
      resources :response_thread_updates do
      end
    end
  end
  
  root to: "responses#new"
end
```

There is an existing `response_thread` on the `response` that I am editing. I haven't even *tried* to update the response_thread_update because I'm getting caught up on just the first level down. There aren't other changes to the application, as I created a new app to work on this problem. I'm just struggling through learning Rails, so please let me know what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: Is it really not saving the updates to the DB? Or are you just worried by the `Unpermitted parameter: :response_thread` ? That shouldn't be an issue because you don't actually need the `:response_thread` in the `response_params` method

Comment: could you please share code for update action?

Comment: @Clara unfortunately it is not saving the update to the DB.

Comment: @SampatBadhe the edit actions from all controllers are empty (exactly as they were generated with scaffolds)

Comment: @MarkMerritt unfortunately not, same error.

Comment: I cannot spot anyhting from the code you provided. I suggest you add a debugger like pry-byebug and inspect what happens in the controller... maybe a validation problem?

Comment: There’s an issue with your form setup because you should get a `response_thread_attributes` param that’s hashed by response thread ID. Possibly change `fields_for :response_thread` to `:response_threads`. That’s definitely wrong but I don’t know that it will fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

first, let check [how StrongParameters permit attributes](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb#L595-L610):

- a `StrongParameters` wrap your input params (a `Hash`)
- if a permit attribute is a scalar (String or Symbol) then it only allows if your input params has any key equals that attribute.
- if a permit attribute is a Hash then it will loop through attribute's keys and check each scalar (as above), in case of empty hash, it'll allow anything.

in your case, you setup a permit attribute `response_thread` as scalar, but your input parameters contains a Hash `response_thread`, so `StrongParameters` cannot find and it'll return `Unpermitted parameter` error.

```rb
params = ActionController::Parameters.new({"response"=>{"response_thread"=>{"name"=>"asd"}}, "commit"=>"Update Response", "id"=>"1"}

# scalar
params.require(:response).permit(:response_thread) # Unpermitted parameter: :response_thread
# hash
params.require(:response).permit(response_thread: :name) # ok
params.require(:response).permit(response_thread: [:name]) # ok
# empty hash
params.require(:response).permit(response_thread: {}) # ok
```

second, the way you setup permit `nested attributes` incorrect, it should be
`params.require(:response).permit(:name, response_threads_attributes: [:id, :name])` (note that `response_threads` not `response_thread`)
and also in view
`<%= f.fields_for :response_threads do |ff| %>`